# Laravel has relationship query on another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I have a user model and a Schedule model. I am trying to use relationships in Laravel instead of doing a join. Is it possible to return all users that have shifts where shift time = 'x' ? I would like to return all users that have shifts between a specific date range.

```
$users = User::select('name','location','id AS user_id')->has('shift')>where('schedule.startTime', $start)->get();
```

This obviously doesn't work because the start column exists in the Schedule Model.

In my **User Model** I have:

```
public function shift() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Schedule');
}
```

In my **Schedule Model** I have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

In my Schedule Controller I am using the below which works but I need to narrow down by my results by a where clause:

```
$users = User::select('name','location','id AS user_id')->has('shift')->get();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at
[eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Something like the following should do the trick.

```
User::whereHas('schedule', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('startTime', $start);
})->get();
```

Comment: This is the way! Thank you for your help, missed this in the Docs.